# Rails webserver connection fail

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, connection, webserver

I can't connect to browser with rails. 'rails s' gives me:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport- 4.0.0/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:282: warning: circular argument reference - now
    => Booting WEBrick
    => Rails 4.0.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
    => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
    => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
    [2016-03-06 14:06:07] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
    [2016-03-06 14:06:07] INFO  ruby 2.3.0 (2015-12-25) [x86_64-darwin15]
    [2016-03-06 14:06:07] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=4336 port=3000
```

When putting 'localhost:3000' into browser I get following error message:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished

Rails.root: /Users/annetteroberts/Sites/simple_cms
```

Looks like a simple problem!

This is what my log spits out

```
    tarted GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-07 21:05:50 +0000
    ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished          (ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished):
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:546:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:79:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:53:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:51:in `restore_query_cache_settings'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:43:in `rescue in call'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__922298227330934617__call__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:140:in `service'
  /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:96:in `run'
  /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:296:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (2.5ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (2.4ms)
  Rendered /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (63.7m
```

Comment: Check the connection with the database. The webbrowser is reaching the server but the server can't connect with the DB. Why I'm supposing that? Because the error comes from ActiveRecord, not from the browser.

Comment: What does it say in the log file?

Comment: wanted to post log here but character restricted...Thx for your help guys